# How to run node pg in Cloudflare Pages (server-side for CockroachDB)

Tags: postgresql, svelte, cloudflare, sveltekit, cockroachdb

I'm trying to tighten up my database calls, and I'd *really* like to be able to just use the `pg` node package in my `+page.server.ts` file in my SvelteKit app. Having to call a lambda to get the data is slow (cold starts etc) and I feel like I can polyfill pg to make it work in a worker/function in CF. Has anybody had success in doing so? I tried to use @supabase/postgrest-js (found on some weird blog but I can't find it again), but I got this error: `FetchError: Request cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials:`

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the 'example' code I'm using in a Lambda at the moment:

```
import pg from 'pg'
import format from 'pg-format'
const { Client, Pool } = pg

export const readFromDbPromptRecipes = async (event) => {
    /* 
        Can either pass limit and offset to retrieve list, or an id to retrieve a single row
    */

    // Set defaults if none exist
    const { id = null, limit = 20, offset = 0 } = event.queryStringParameters ?? event
    console.log('params: ', event.queryStringParameters ?? id, limit, offset)

    // Default query (list recent results)
    let query = format('Select * FROM outputs ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT %L OFFSET %L', limit, offset)

    if (!!id) {
        // If there is an ID specified, only return the one row
        console.log('There is an id')
        query = format(`SELECT * from outputs WHERE _id = %L`, id)
    }

    const dbClient = new Client(***CONNECTION_STRING***)
    try {
        await dbClient.connect()
        const dbResponse = await dbClient.query(query)
        return dbResponse.rows
    } catch (e) {
        return {
            error: 'There was an error with your request. Please refresh the page to try again.'
        }
    } finally {
        dbClient.end()
    }
    return 'Nothing to retrieve';
}
```

Comment: so you run ascript that you  can't find, and you don't show the script, so how can someone help you?

Comment: Easily. The first question. Has anybody managed to get the `pg` node package running in Cloudflare workers. It's a pretty straightforward question.

Comment: The comment in the middle is another solution I tried but couldn't get to work.

Comment: see the manual https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting about connection methods and when you are at it about prepared statements as well

Comment: It's the fact that Cloudflare Workers don't use node - but Chrome v8. There is webpack polyfill that allows you to use node packages, but pg isn't immediately set up for it. The other option - PostgREST doesn't work with Cockroach, giving the error I mentioned previously. This code works fine in a lambda.